# Dynamic image resizing in a responsive grid

Tags: javascript, image, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, resize

I’m looking for a stable, fast dynamic image resizing service that works in a responsive, grid design. I run a website that features large numbers of photos displayed using a bootstrap grid.

I'd like to upload the images once at full resolution and then have them dynamically resized based on their display size in the grid. The images are displayed as 100% width and then constrained by the size of the bootstrap grid cell. Some are displayed side by side, some are displayed at full container width.

I currently use http://ReSRC.it to resize and serve my images. I specify the URL once and JS on the client side requests the most appropriate sized image. They're the only service I can find that uses the image's display size. The viewport size isn't relevant here because a smaller viewport may actually require a larger image if the grid collapses and the images are no longer displayed side by side.

I'm not unhappy with ReSRC.it, I'd just like to understand what other options I have (especially when it comes to speed/reliability – two of ReSRC's flaws, IMO). It would seem that CloudFlare's Mirage feature appears to do something similar, but I can't find any information on whether it uses viewport or display (is there a JS component?) size. I don't know whether CloudFlare astroturfs, but it seems as though any information that does exist on the service is the same marketing fluff repeated over and over again.

Other services I've seen resize based on URL paramaters, but that doesn't help me as I don't know the size of the image until the client loads. That means I'm pretty much limited to a semi-javascript solution, right?

Answer (score 0):

You need [Slimmage.js](https://github.com/imazen/slimmage). It's fast, respects CSS rules and breakpoints, is accessible, and doesn't make duplicate requests.

Also see
[Dynamic image resizing in the Cloud for Responsive website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24235567/dynamic-image-resizing-in-the-cloud-for-responsive-website/24239331#24239331)